# MVC app erroring on SqlServerCe.4.0 provider after converting to Sql Express

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, sql-server-ce

I have an MVC application that I originally wrote using Entity Framework with SQLCE 4.0. I decided to use Sql Express instead. I have converted the project and everything works great but if I remove the EntityFramework.SqlServerCompact NuGet package then my application errors initializing the DbContext.

Here is the error:

```
Schema specified is not valid. Errors: 
(0,0) : error 0152: No Entity Framework provider found for the ADO.NET provider with invariant name 'System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0'. Make sure the provider is registered in the 'entityFramework' section of the application config file.
```

I have made sure that web.config for the UI layer, and app.config for my data domain assembly are both clear of any references to SqlCE, SqlServerCe, etc. I've done a file level search through the entire solution and everything seems clean, but if I remove that NuGet package, the site crashes.

I've found a similar issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19109976/entity-framework-using-the-wrong-connection-provider) but no solution was ever listed.

What am I missing?

Here is my web.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
    For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
    http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301880
    -->
<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
    </configSections>
    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="EowDataContext" connectionString="Server=.\EOW;Database=Eow.Sample;User ID=Eow.Sample;Password=mypass"
            providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    </connectionStrings>
    <appSettings>
        <add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0" />
        <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
        <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
        <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
    </appSettings>
    <system.web>
        <authentication mode="None" />
        <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.1" />
        <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.1" />
    </system.web>
    <system.webServer>
        <modules>
            <remove name="FormsAuthenticationModule" />
        </modules>
        <handlers>
            <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
            <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />
            <remove name="TRACEVerbHandler" />
            <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
        </handlers>
    </system.webServer>
    <runtime>
        <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
            <dependentAssembly>
                <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Optimization" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
                <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-1.1.0.0" newVersion="1.1.0.0" />
            </dependentAssembly>
            <dependentAssembly>
                <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
                <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.5.2.14234" newVersion="1.5.2.14234" />
            </dependentAssembly>
            <dependentAssembly>
                <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
                <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.1.0.0" newVersion="2.1.0.0" />
            </dependentAssembly>
            <dependentAssembly>
                <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin.Security" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
                <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.1.0.0" newVersion="2.1.0.0" />
            </dependentAssembly>
            <dependentAssembly>
                <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" culture="neutral" />
                <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.0.0" newVersion="6.0.0.0" />
            </dependentAssembly>
            <dependentAssembly>
                <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Core" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
                <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.1.0.0" newVersion="2.1.0.0" />
            </dependentAssembly>
            <dependentAssembly>
                <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Http" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
                <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.1.0.0" newVersion="5.1.0.0" />
            </dependentAssembly>
            <dependentAssembly>
                <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
                <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
            </dependentAssembly>
            <dependentAssembly>
                <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
                <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
            </dependentAssembly>
            <dependentAssembly>
                <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
                <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.1.0.0" newVersion="5.1.0.0" />
            </dependentAssembly>
        </assemblyBinding>
    </runtime>
    <entityFramework>
        <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
        <providers>
            <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
        </providers>
    </entityFramework>
    <system.data>
        <DbProviderFactories>
            <add name="SqlClient Data Provider" invariant="System.Data.SqlClient" description=".Net Framework Data Provider for SqlServer" type="System.Data.SqlClient.SqlClientFactory, System.Data,      Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
        </DbProviderFactories>
    </system.data>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Are you using an edmx, or code first?

Comment: I am using code first.

Comment: Obviously you reference sqlce somewhere, either in .settings or in code based configuration DbConfiguration class...

Comment: pcbliss, did you ever get an answer?  I have the same problem.  Note that the issue you reference mentions having to redo all the migrations.  I don't see why that would be necessary as the migrations don't mention providers.

Comment: Dave, I ultimately wound up rebuilding my project by deleting the old project files and adding my code and relevant nugget packages back in. I don't think I had to rebuild my migrations, but it has been a while.

Answer (score 1):

We also had the same problem. We tried to migrate from SQL Compact to SQL Express. We chased and removed any reference to SQL Compact in the solution but that was not enough.

Our final move was to clean completely the solution (any visual studio that are not needed to open the solution):

- remove obj, debug, release...
- remove .vs folder (that's probably the one)

Finally we reopened the solution, tried again and got it work.
Hope it helps.